# How can I access packages installed in a virtual environment?

Tags: python

I've created and activated a virtual environment on my mac and I've installed a package into the environment successfully via pip. Now I'd like to write a basic python script that uses said package but it spawns a "ModuleNotFoundError:". The virtual environment is activated while I run the code. I'm using Sublime Text 3 if that's relevant.

Answer (score 0):

Just figured it out. Sublime Text doesn't access the active venv. I just have to type python3 myfile.py in the terminal and then the code works.